# Error: Cannot find module './replaceSymbols.js' from css-loader when trying to locally serve application

Tags: css-loader

I have an error when trying to run my app during the 'npm run serve' :

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>   Error: Cannot find module '**./replaceSymbols.js**'

It is linked to the styles, as when I remove all the `<style>` sections of all files, and remove `import './assets/app.scss'` from my main.js, I don't get the error. It occurs with css and scss, as I get the error with `<style>` and `<style lang="scss">`.

I tried a `npm install` and `npm update`, or to reinstall `css-loader` but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea why this occurs and how to fix that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve this issue by deleting all dependencies and install everything back again. I run:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```